# Bootstrap's Panels with the same height

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have 3 bootstrap panels one next to another. They height of each of them is variable according to the information retrieved from the database. I want that the height of the 3 of them match. If one of them has less info, anyway adjust the height to the taller panel. I know that I must use display:table and display:table-cell but as Bootstrap has some nested divs to achieve the Panel view, it's very confusing... what do you suggest? Here is the code of each of my panels (very default to the Bootstrap example):

```
           <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-push-1">                 
                 <div class="panel panel-default">     
                    <div class="panel-body panelLoggedIn">
                        <a href="#">Example Link</a>                        
                        <a href="#">Example Link</a>
                        <a href="#">Example Link</a>
                        <a href="#">Example Link</a>
                        <a href="#">Example Link</a>
                        <a href="#">Example Link</a>
                        <a href="#">Example Link</a>
                        <a href="#">Example Link</a>
                    </div>
                </div>                  
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-push-1">                
                 <div class="panel panel-default">     
                    <div class="panel-body panelLoggedIn">
                        <a href="#">Example Link</a>                        
                        <a href="#">Example Link</a>
                    </div>
                </div>                  
            </div>

           <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-push-1">                 
                 <div class="panel panel-default">     
                    <div class="panel-body panelLoggedIn">
                        <a href="#">Example Link</a>                        
                        <a href="#">Example Link</a>
                        <a href="#">Example Link</a>
                        <a href="#">Example Link</a>
                    </div>
                </div>                  
            </div>
```

Comment: AFAIK, you can't mix the `display: table` approach with `push`/`pull` classes, due to how HTML tables work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May do this only by css. Add **row** div for panels.

```
<div class="row equal">
   <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-push-1"> 
     ...
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-push-1"> 
     ...
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-push-1"> 
     ...
   </div>
</div>
```

And add CSS

```
.equal, .equal > div[class*='col-'] {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    flex:1 1 auto;
}
```

Demo in [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/127828)

Comment: note, that this is not responsive. Columns not going to stack on mobile, but rather shrink

Answer (score 14):

If you do not want to use Flexbox and you do want to support legacy browsers, use [jquery.matchHeight.js](https://github.com/liabru/jquery-match-height). It's responsive and small.

Put a `.row` around the columns with a class of your choice:

```
<div class="row equal-height-panels">
... bootstrap columns with panels inside
</div>
```

Initialize the script using the class you created:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.equal-height-panels .panel').matchHeight();
  });
```

**DEMO: http://jsbin.com/diyux/2**

Do not forget your .container or .container-fluid around the .row since that will remove the horizontal scrollbars from the negative left and right margins on the .row. Learn more about the bootstrap grid if that doesn't make sense.

Comment: do we need to include any js library also for that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this plugin

http://css-tricks.github.io/Equalizer/

http://tsvensen.github.io/equalize.js/

Just customize according to your requirement .